# AppExchange Product Listing Documentation resources required

Tags: appexchange

We are in the process of developing the Salesforce Application. Our goal is to list the Application on AppExchange. While I am aware of the overall AppExchange Listing process, Security Reviews etc. I am specifically looking for any resources if available to refer for preparing the documentation required to list the Product on AppExchange.
Kindly share the resources if you have come across any. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no *required* documentation, but salesforce.com [recommends the following](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.214.0.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/develop_documentation.htm?search_text=documentation):

> Configure Option
>   You can include a Configure option for installers. This option can link to installation and configuration details, such as:
>
> - Provisioning the external service of a composite app
> - Custom app settings

...

> Data Sheet
>
> Give installers the fundamental information they need to know about your app before they install.
>
> Customization and Enhancement Guide
>
> Let installers know what they must customize after installation as part of their implementation.
>
> Custom Help
>
> You can provide custom help for your custom object records and custom fields.

They also recommend that you follow the [Salesforce Style Guide for Documentation and User Interface Text](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/214/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_pubs_style_guide.pdf).